# How to read csv formatted numeric data into Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with two formatted columns that currently read in as objects:

1. contains percentage values which read in as strings like '0.01%'.  The % is always at the end.
2. contains currency values which read in as string like '$1234.5'.

I have tried using the split function to remove the % or $ inside the dataframe, then using float on the result of the split.  This will print the correct result but will not assign the value.  It also gives a type error that float does not have split function, even though I do the split before the float????

Comment: Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

"""
The example df looks like this:
    col1     col2
0  3.04%  $100.25
1  0.15%    $1250
2  0.22%     $322
3  1.30%     $956
4  0.49%     $621
"""

df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.split('%', expand=True)[[0]]
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.split('$', 1, expand=True)[[1]]

df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the apply method.

With

```
df['first_col'] = df['first_col'].apply(lambda x: float(x.strip('%'))
```